# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException when running external method

Tags: java, sql, swing, nullpointerexception

Background:- Im trying to run an update query to simply change the boolean value from a 0 to a 1 if it meets certain criteria i.e. the row matches the registration number of the vehicle and also the task is set to open i.e. boolean 0.  This is to to enable to close a task in the database once complete

I am calling a method from the "Ambulance_GUI" class in the "TaskQuery" class and this query works fine in SQL.  I have also got it to work with a "Frankenstein" method in the Java pragram but the compiler was saying uncompilable code even though it was working therefore I am re-writing it.

However, now I am getting a NullPointerException error and cannot see what I am doing wrong, it maybe because I have been staring at it for too long but I cannot get them working!  I apologise if its something stupid but any help would be great!

This is the method call:

```
private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        TaskQueryClass NTQ2 = new TaskQueryClass(this.vehicleReg);

        NTQ2.updateTaskStatus1();
```

and this is the method in the TaskQuery Class:

```
public void updateTaskStatus1() //throws SQLException
    {
        try {
            DatabaseConnection db = new DatabaseConnection();

            stmt = conn.createStatement();

         String newQuery= "UPDATE Task\n" +
                "SET TaskClosed='1', TaskClosedDate=CONVERT (date, SYSDATETIME())\n" +
                "FROM Vehicle AS V\n" +
                "JOIN Task AS T\n" +
                "ON V.TaskID = T.Task_ID\n" +
                "WHERE TaskClosed = '0'\n" +
                "AND V.VehicleRegistrationNumber = '"+this.vehicleID+"'";

         int rows = stmt.executeUpdate(newQuery);
         System.out.println(rows + " Row is Updated Successfully. ");

        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        } finally {
            //closing connection
            //conn.close();
            //stmt.close();
        }
    }
```

The Stack trace is as follows:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ambulance.project.TaskQueryClass.updateTaskStatus1(TaskQueryClass.java:130)
    at ambulance.project.Ambulance_GUI.jButton4ActionPerformed(Ambulance_GUI.java:380)
    at ambulance.project.Ambulance_GUI.access$200(Ambulance_GUI.java:19)
    at ambulance.project.Ambulance_GUI$3.actionPerformed(Ambulance_GUI.java:110)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

It complains about the `stmt = conn.createStatement();` line within the method first of all and then the next line it highlights is the `NTQ2.updateTaskStatus1();` method call. next it complains about the Ambulance_GUI Constructor line itself then it goes into the Generated code for the JFrame.

The connection is initialised as so:

```
public class TaskQueryClass {

    Connection conn = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    private final String vehicleID
```

Comment: Post the entire exception with full stack trace and point out for us the line it complains about.

Comment: I have added both now

Comment: Where is `conn` declared and initialized?

Comment: In the Class Constructor:  public class TaskQueryClass {
    
    Connection conn = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    private final String vehicleID

Comment: Where `conn` gets a value other than `null`?

Comment: nowhere else, is this my problem?  Im new to Java and this is first program so making basic errors

Comment: That's exactly what causes [`NPE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html).  You are not allowed to call any methods on `null` objects.

Comment: ok, any suggestions on how to rectify it? do i simply call conn = something?

Comment: What does your `DatabaseConnection` constructor do?

Comment: It calls a db connection method in database connection class, I could replace it with the full connection method which would probably solve the problem thinking about it but I was trying to avoid having that inside other classes as it looks untidy.

Comment: You really should learn [`JDBC`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/processingsqlstatements.html) before writing a code like this.

Comment: yeah tell that to my instructors who did a "full" course of java in 2 weeks plus SQl and set us this assignment.  Thanks for your help

Comment: Post your `DatabaseConnection` class. If you are lucky it creates the connection you need.

Comment: yeah the database connection class is tried and tested, I have lots of other classes using it ok but this is the first insert query so was a bit of an unknown.  Exactly as you said I have added the connection information into the method and defined the conn as not null at the top and it works a treat now error free.  Thankyou very much for your help.  I can get some sleep now!